# How to bind data from another component without a http request in angular 14

Tags: angular

Basically all I wanna do is display some data according to the item I clicked on the component before.

I created a component similar to a HousesComponent, which has a list of houses and their names. In order to display that information on that component, I have an interface called Houses which looks like the following:

```
export interface Houses {
 id: number
 name: string
}
```

Also, I have an array called housesArray which contains all the houses names and their ids:

```
export var housesArray = [
 {name: 'pink house', id: 1},{name: 'blue house', id: 2}
]
```

In order to change the route parameters, I followed some tips and put this subscribe function inside the ngOnInit of my HousesTemplateComponent (which is the one that is going to recieve and display the data selected).

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.getHouseById(params['id']))
```

My app-routing.module has 'house/id' as the path for the HousesTemplateComponent.
The url changes perfectly according to each house I click on. Athough, when I try to bind the house name, it comes as undefined.

The way I looked up to do it was by creating a get function that requires an id as the parameter. Then, I get the house's id try to subscribe the house variable the information into it.

```
  getHouseById(id: number){
    this.houseService.getHouseById(id).subscribe((data: IHouses) => this.house= data)
  }
```

The example I followed was made consuming a backend response, so they have an api for that. In my case, instead of using apis and a database (since I do not need one to show simple information), I am trying to access data from the housesArray.

The houseService has this get function:

```
house$ = new Subject();

getHouseById(id: number): Observable<IHouses>{
  return this.house$.asObservable();
}
```

I am new at creating these type of routes without consuming an api, so I think the problem could be on the getHouseById function on my HouseService. I would appreaciate any help! Thanks in advance.

**Edit (solution):**

Thanks to @Michael Ziluck, here is the outcome of the help I got from them.
[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j1djof?file=src/app/houses-template/houses-template.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main Problems

1. There are no references to `housesArray` in your `getHouseById` method
2. `ActivatedRoute` parameters are *always* strings, not numbers. Any number value whose equality is checked using `===` *must* be parsed to a number first.

### Recommended solution

This approach replicates the functionality of GET request to a REST API. First part should be the usage in the component, second part is the use in the template.

`houses.component.ts`

```js
house$!: Observable<Houses>;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.house$ = this.route.params.pipe(
    map(params => parseInt(params["id"])), // could also just do +params["id"] but that is a less safe operation
    switchMap(id => this.getHouseById(id)),
  );
}

getHouseById(id: number): Observable<Houses> {
  const house = housesArray.find(house => house.id === id);
  return house === undefined
    ? throwError(() => new Error(`House not found with id ${id}`))
    : of(house);
}
```

`houses.component.html`

```
<div>House ID: {{(house | async).id}}</div>
<div>House Name: {{(house | async).name}}</div>
```

#### If not using strict mode

Strict mode prevents the use of `null` or `undefined` when using type parameters. If you aren't using it, you can change that first line to be simply:

```
houses$: Subject<Houses> = new BehaviorSubject<Houses>(null);
```

#### Debugging

If things still aren't popping up for you, try some of these debug steps. For each of them, check out the console and see when things start returning as `null` or `undefined`.

##### Check that `housesArray` is imported correctly

In `getHouseById`, try adding these log statements right *after* the line that starts with `const house`:

```js
console.log("housesArray: ", housesArray);
console.log("house: ", house);
```

#### Check that the `map` and `switchMap` work correctly:

Change the operators within `pipe` in the `ngOnInit` to look like this:

```js
this.house$ = this.route.params.pipe(
  tap(params => console.log("params: ", params)),
  map(params => parseInt(params["id"])),
  tap(id => console.log("id: ", id)),
  switchMap(id => this.getHouseById(id)),
  tap(house => console.log("house: ", house)),
);
```

### Alternatives

There is no single "right" way, but I would discourage use of the other answer here. In it, the `houses$` property will be typed as `Observable<IHouses[]>` which then forces you to filter it every time it is called.

Option 1:

```js
getHouseById(id: number): Observable<Houses | undefined> {
  return of(housesArray.find(house => house.id === +id));
}
```

Option 2 (if you're dead set on using a Subject :

```js
houses$: ReplaySubject<Houses>;

constructor() {
  this.houses$ = new ReplaySubject<Houses>(housesArray.length);
  housesArray.forEach(house => houses$.next(house));
}

getHouseById(id: number): Observable<Houses> {
  return this.houses$.pipe(first(house => house.id === +id));
}
```

Am a little confused on what `IHouses` is as the interface you described above is called simply `House`. Going to answer this operating under the assumption that `IHouses` = `House` and it was just a copy-paste typo.

Comment: Hi Michael! Thank you for your help. I found your solutions pretty interesting and tested them. Although, I can't acess any information from the housesArray when I try to bind them on the HousesTemplateComponent. With the first option, I get the throwError and the console also says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading name)" when I bind {{house.name}}

Comment: @KimiH Went ahead and made a significant update that should be more clear!

Comment: I implemented those methods on the template where I am trying to display the data. The housesArray is correctly imported and I can console.log it. The console.log("house", house) returns undefined though. The id comes correctly, but I still can't acess the name that corresponds to that id.

Comment: @MichaelZiluck, About your "recomended solution" (It's for understand, not a critic) Can you explain why you use `.subscribe(this.houses$);`? I feel you can use `houses$=this.route.params.pipe(switchMap(params=> this.getHouseById(params['id']))`

Comment: @KimiH, that would be because the id that you have stored in `housesArray` uses a `number` for the `id` property while the one in the `ActivatedRoute` uses a `string`. I've updated the example code with that in mind and actually ran it all locally this time so you should be good now.

Comment: @Eliseo that is actually a way more clever way to do it! Nice catch. Updating my example code with that as well. Still going to keep the intermediate `map` call because I think it's cleaner conceptually but is ultimately unnecessary.

Comment: @MichaelZiluck I followed your updated instructions but the console error still says "Cannot read properties of undefined". I don't know if that is because of the kind of route I am trying to make (houses.componenet.html which has a button that leads to the selected house) and the house-template.component.html/.ts, where I am adding the functions to call the selected house. If it sounds confusing, I can create and share an example on stackblitz.

Comment: Please share the StackBlitz, that code I posted definitely works locally so the issue must be something else in your setup

Comment: @MichaelZiluck I highly appreciate your time and patience! After creating an example of the project on Stackblitz, I found out that your first option was already working, but I got the wrong variable to bind on the template.html. It should be `{(house$ | async).id}}` but instead I only put `{(house | async).id}}` by mistake.  I'll add the example link on my post.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the array to an observable use `of`.

To find the house with the correct id use `pipe`, `map`, `find`.

```
  house$ = of(housesArray);

  getHouseById(id: number): Observable<IHouses> {
    return this.house$.pipe(map((array) => array.find((h) => h.id === id)));
  }
```

### Docs

of: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of

pipe: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe

map: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map

### Example

```js
const housesArray = [
 {name: 'pink house', id: 1},{name: 'blue house', id: 2}
]

const house$ = rxjs.of(housesArray);

function getHouseById(id) {
  return house$.pipe(rxjs.map((array) => array.find((h) => h.id === id)));
}

getHouseById(1).subscribe((h)=>console.log("House 1 name:", h.name))
getHouseById(2).subscribe((h)=>console.log("House 2 name:", h.name))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@%5E7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

---

Although I'm not really sure I see the point in observables when you could just do:

```
  getHouseById(id: number): IHouses {
    housesArray.find((h) => h.id === id));
  }
```

Maybe you think change detection is tied to them in some way? Like hooks in React? That's not the case.

Comment: What would be the motivation behind using `of` in this case? The intended use-case is to replicate a GET request with an integer key. With that being the case, typing the class property as `Observable<IHouses[]>` by calling `of(housesArray)` is just inconvenient.

Comment: It's quick and simple